# how to get UItableviewcell from cgpoint?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uipangesturerecognizer

I am writing an app which requires dragging a button from a UIView to a UItableview and based on where the user has left off i need to know which tableview cell the user has left his finger.

This is required because based on which tableviewcell the user has left off i need to updated that in that specific cell.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use UITableView instance method

```
- (NSIndexPath *)indexPathForRowAtPoint:(CGPoint)point;
```

It returns you index path, and after that you can get your cell instance using method

```
- (__kindof UITableViewCell *)cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use UITableView's rectFor[whatever] methods to determine which cell your point intersects.

For example, you could iterate over the visible index paths with:

```
- (CGRect)rectForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

And check intersection with the CGRectContainsPoint() function.